# How to configure tablecellproperties in ckeditor 5

Tags: ckeditor, alignment

Maybe because I am an autodidact, but eventho I've coding for some years I cannot seem to figure this out. I feel like a noob. And this is a lot of text for a rather small question.

I set up ckeditor 5 without problems. But I need to be able to use tables and do a little formatting. Adding tables was not a problem either.

But then I needed to adjust the vertical alignment of the tablecells. There's a nice description of how to use colors, but that's no what I need.

Currently I have my tabel's contenttoolbar configured like this

```
contentToolbar: [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties' ]
```

Then I want to configure the table(cell)properties, something like this:

```
tableCellProperties: { verticalAlignment: [ 'top', 'bottom' ] }
```

Now I know whatever I wrote next to tabelCellProperties is not correct. But I just haven't got a clue what I write there. I searched through the ckeditor docs, Stackoverflow, googled to other sites. I just can't seem to find what must be done.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it...
Apparently my custom build had missed the plugins TableProperties and TableCellProperties. Eventho I was quite sure I had them selected, I had not.

I created a new build, et voilá! It works like a charm.

Tip for airheads like me: Make a screenshot of your build, because its hard to tell afterwards what you did or didn't include.

Comment: How did you create a custom build? The explanation in CkEditor5 pages is not clear to me at all. Do you have any other links or  user guides available?